# External Storage

Tags: deployment, sd-card

I am developing an app where i have thousands of images i am reading from the sdcard. I would like to say when i deploy the app, the images are downloaded together with the app. I have been trying to find a solution to this but no help. Please help!!!

The images are used as bitmap resources for imageViews. the are too many that I can't put them in drawable because they will make the app size too big.

Right now i have manually copied them over to the storage of the device i am accessing them from there. If I want to test thye app on another device then i have to copy the images folder again to the external drive of that device. Is there a way i can include them in the solution without putting them in drwable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to keep your images on some web server and try to download the images from here.This will avaoid coping images all the time to devices .
So here is what you can do :
1 ) Upload the images on some server .
2) Also you can have a xml which will have urls of all the image.
3) When you start your application you first fetch the XML and get the urls.
4) then using these urls you can lazy load the images in your app.

try to read and understand this concept [here](http://androidexample.com/Download_Images_From_Web_And_Lazy_Load_In_ListView_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=112&aaid=134) :

Thanks